# Attempted import error: 'BrowseRouter' is not exported from 'react-router-dom' (imported as 'Router')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I dont know why i am getting this error, i have tried searching online and i saw some suggestions which i tried out but the error wouldn't clear. Please does anyone have any idea on what am doing wrong.
Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';

import { BrowseRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Join from './components/Join';
import Chat from './components/Chat';

const App = () => (
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Join} />
        <Route path="/chat" exact component={Chat} />
    </Router>
);

export default App;
```

Comment: There's a typo, it should be `import { BrowserRouter }`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`react-router-dom` doesn’t export `BrowseRouter`, it exports `BrowserRouter`.

[Documentation here](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

Answer (score 3):

there is a misspelled on BrowserRouter**  you have it  as  BrowseRouter.
it should be BrowserRouter not  BrowseRouter.
try this

import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";